# Pymongo match and sort

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a number of documents with selection dates and location id's.  I am trying to build a pipeline that will match on documents with a selection time that falls within the last hour then run a count on those.  My dates are in mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss format but seem to be represented as strings in MongoDB

Here is what I have so far

```
last_hour = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
now = dateime.datetime.now()

pipeline = [
    {"$match":{"select_time":{"$gt":last_hour,"$lte":now}}},
    {"$unwind":"$loc_id"},
    {"$group": {"_id":"$loc_id"}},
    {"$sort": SON([("_id", -1), ("count", -1)])}
]

for i in list(db.loc_counter.aggregate(pipeline)):
    print i
```

Everything but the match piece is working.  I am not sure if it is a date format issue or what.

Comment: what does a typical loc_counter document look like?

Comment: Very simple record only two real fields.    {
 "_id" : ObjectId("5aa02df07b30c14842ddaf2f"),
 "loc_id" : "176",
 "select_time" : "03-22-2018 10:22:40"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the current format of time to ISODate format. 
You may want to write a migration to convert current `select_time` to ISODate format ([See supported formats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/).)

The projection stage of the pipeline can become inefficient when the number of documents in the collection gets huge.

Also, fix the script inserting the documents in the wrong date format to insert document with `select_time` field in ISODate format.

```
lasthour = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)

pipeline = [
    {
        '$project': {
            'select_time_ISODate': {
                '$dateFromString': {
                    'dateString': {
                        '$concat': [
                            {'$substr': ['$select_time', 6, 4]}, 
                            '-', {'$substr': ['$select_time', 0, 2]}, 
                            '-', {'$substr': ['$select_time', 3, 2]}, 
                            'T', {'$substr': ['$select_time', 11, 8]}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            'loc_id': 1
        }
    },
    {'$match': {'select_time_ISODate': {'$gte': lasthour}}},
    {'$count': 'num_logs_since_past_hour'}
]
cursor = db.loc_counter.aggregate(pipeline)

print(tuple(cursor))
```

Suppose that `select_time` were in the right date format, you'll only need the match and count stage of the current pipeline.

Comment: Converting to ISO date format fixed the issue.  THank you!

Answer (score 0):

**$dateFromString** works fine, But my suggestion is store select_time as **ISO date** only. The datetime formats stored as string are not useful , You can not use them for sorting or in date comparison conditions. Everytime projecting the select_time as ISO datetime will be an unnecessery pipeline.